# I am trying to find movie has been rented more than "Silverado"? Need output: title and number of times it is rented

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find if a movie has been rented more than "Silverado". I need output: title and the number of times it is rented.

[image: mmrental db]

[image: mmmovie db]

```
SELECT MOVIE_TITLE, movie_value 
FROM mm_movie 
WHERE MOVIE_TITLE >= (SELECT MOVIE_TITLE 
FROM mm_movie 
WHERE UPPER(MOVIE_TITLE)='Silverado');
```

With this code I get output: no data found. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

As you posted images, I didn't feel like typing that much to create test case so I picked just a few movies. Lines #1 - 14 represent sample data - you don't type that. Query that actually *does something* begins at line #16.

Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  mm_movie(movie_id, movie_title) as
  4    (select  1, 'Alien'         from dual union all
  5     select  5, 'Jaws'          from dual union all
  6     select  7, 'Silverado'     from dual union all
  7     select 11, 'Deep Blue Sea' from dual
  8    ),
  9  mm_rental (rental_id, movie_id) as
 10    (select 5,  5 from dual union all -- jaws          - rented once
 11     select 8,  7 from dual union all -- Silverado     - rented once
 12     select 1, 11 from dual union all -- deep blue sea - rented twice
 13     select 6, 11 from dual           -- deep blue sea
 14    )
 15  -- query you might be interested in
 16  select a.movie_title,
 17         count(*) rented
 18  from mm_movie a join mm_rental b on b.movie_id = a.movie_id
 19  group by a.movie_title
 20  having count(*) > -- subquery returns number of how many times
 21                    -- the "Silverado" was rented
 22                    (select count(*) cnt_silverado
 23                     from mm_rental r join mm_movie m on m.movie_id = r.movie_id
 24                     where m.movie_title = 'Silverado'
 25                    );

MOVIE_TITLE       RENTED
------------- ----------
Deep Blue Sea          2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `JOIN` the two tables and then use `GROUP BY` and aggregation to find the counts and then use conditional analytic functions compare to the number of times Silverado was rented:

```sql
SELECT movie_id, movie_title
FROM   (
  SELECT m.movie_id,
         MAX(m.movie_title) AS movie_title,
         COUNT(r.movie_id) AS times_rented,
         MAX(
           CASE MAX(m.movie_title) WHEN 'Silverado' THEN COUNT(r.movie_id) END
         ) OVER ()
           AS times_silverado_rented
  FROM   mm_movie m
         LEFT OUTER JOIN mm_rental r
         ON ( m.movie_id = r.movie_id )
  GROUP BY m.movie_id
)
WHERE times_rented > times_silverado_rented
```

*(Note: this should still work if Silverado had been rented zero times.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ecddd93bbcefd32c9f504d040cbb258b)*

Answer (score -1):

This might help.

```
    WITH TITLES_RENTED as (
  SELECT
    MOVIE_TITLE,
    COUNT(1) TIMES_RENTED
  FROM
    MM_MOVIE
  GROUP BY
    MOVIE_TITLE
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TITLES_RENTED
WHERE
  TIMES_RENTED > (
    SELECT
      COUNT(1) S_CNT
    FROM
      MM_MOVIE
    WHERE
      UPPER(MOVIE_TITLE) = 'SILVERADO'
  )
ORDER BY
  TIMES_RENTED DESC;
```

Comment: Hi brother, it said no data found too. Thank you brother.